# How many elements does the quotient ring have?

Tags: ring-theory

My question today is:
Is polynomial $1+x+x^2$ irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]?$ Let $[1+x+x^2]$ be the ideal of $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$ generated by $1+x+x^2$. Is the quotient ring $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]/[1+x+x^2]$ a field? How many elements does the quotient ring $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]/[1+x+x^2]$ have?

I've answered most of it but I just have to answer this:  How many elements does the quotient ring $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]/[1+x+x^2]$ have?

I know the polynomial is irreducible, and I know it is a field. But how can I answer the last part? I see on the internet that I have to use the division algorithm, but what should I divide? I hope some of you can help me with the last part.

Answer (score 0):

The order of a finite field in general will be $p^n$ where $p$ is the characteristic of the field and n is the degree of the polynomial(or equivalently the dimension of the field over $(1_F)$. You could also go the long route and construct the field explicitly, but it does not appear necessary in this case.

Hint: The characteristic of the field will be equal to the characteristic of $\mathbb{Z}_p$

Comment: Is it true that there exists 25 elements? I will read both of your comments intensive, thanks.

Comment: I see my lecturer did an example on the black board my friend screenshotted, on the black board he was trying to find some inverse but I don't know. It's long time and I were sick in this period.

Comment: With further thought I believe that my friend said that he extended the problem that day (not on the paper). So in fact, the final answer for the last part is just 25 elements, assuming the polynomial is irreducible and a field?

Comment: Thanks. I just were confused about the inverse the lecturer was trying to find. My first thought were it was a "proof" to confirm the 25 elements.

As you can see, algebra is "new" for me.:)

Comment: Ahh thanks. Last question, should I write all 25 elements or it is just okay to write that there exist 25 elements?

Comment: @KasperMedK I don't see why you would need to as the question doesn't ask you to do that, but it can't hurt to do it for the practice as my guess is you will have to know how at some point

Comment: Once again, thank you! I will not write it but just mention that there exists.

Answer (score 0):

**Hints**:

How many elements does a vector space of dimension $d$ over $\mathbf F_5=\mathbf Z/5\mathbf Z$ have?

What is $\dim_{\mathbf F_5} \mathbf F_5[x]/(x^2+x+1)$?